# Installing R packages in RStudio

Tags: software-installation, 18.04, r, rstudio

I am new to working in a Linux environment full-time and am running Ubuntu 18.04. I have installed R and RStudio and am now trying to install all of my packages. I set the CRAN mirror when initially configuring R. I am unable to install packages as I did on Windows (e.g. install packages ('devtools') from the console) and have found some resources to help me install certain packages however I am looking for help (links to helpful resources would be great!) on understanding why the install process is different with Ubuntu and also for installing packages so I can get to work as soon as possible!

Also when I try to use the following to install devtools:

```
sudo apt-get -y install libcurl4-gnutls-dev libxml2-dev libssl-dev
```

I get the following error message:

```
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libcurl4-gnutls-dev amd64 7.58.0-2ubuntu3.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/curl/libcurl4-gnutls-dev_7.58.0-2ubuntu3.1_amd64.deb   
  404 Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]    
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

And when I run with `--fix-missing`, I get the `Failed to fetch` error again.

Comment: Did you remember to run `sudo apt-get update` first? the current version of `libcurl4-gnutls-dev` in the bionic-updates repository appears to be `7.58.0-2ubuntu3.2`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the preferred way to install R packages in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/795925/what-is-the-preferred-way-to-install-r-packages-in-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

@steeldriver Thank you! That helped!

Also, I have come across 2 resources that have been particularly helpful: the CRAN-supported [Ubuntu package install page](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/README.html) and [this other post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/795925/what-is-the-preferred-way-to-install-r-packages-in-ubuntu) on AskUbuntu.

Thank you for your help!