# Problem in executing .sh file in ubuntu

Tags: scripts

[image]
I am trying to install software by running .sh script in ubuntu but every time I am trying to execute the script I found error makee:not found. I have attached the screen shot of it.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots, instead copy the code from the terminal window.

Comment: There is a problem in **line 110 of the script**. Locate the command in line 110 and try to find the cause.

Answer (score 3):

The `make: not found` error can be solved by installing *make*. In all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install make build-essential python2.7 python-pil gcc grass-dev
```

[r.avaflow](http://www.avaflow.org/manuals/r.avaflow_20161104.html) requires the grass-dev package. This command will also install grass-dev version >=7.

Visualization and validation of the model results (flag v) makes use of the R Project for Statistical Computing (recommended version: 3.0.2 or higher). The following packages of R are required in order to fully explore the functionalities offered by r.avaflow: maptools, stats, sp, rgeos, rgdal, ROCR and raster. The code builds on Python 2.7 (the Python Imaging Library PIL is required) and C.

To install these additional dependencies open the terminal and type;

```
sudo apt install r-base r-base-core r-cran-maptools r-cran-sp r-cran-rocr r-cran-raster
```

To install the remaining additional dependencies (stats, rgeos and rgdal) you need to install a package to fetch and install packages from CRAN (the package archive network for the R programming language) by following the instructions at [What is the preferred way to install R packages in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/795925/).

Comment: Thanks alot for the detail reply.

Answer (score 2):

From the error message it looks like the script tries to build the software. For this to work you need some software installed.

This can usually be accomplished with

```
sudo apt install build-essential
```

Are you sure that the desired program is not available in the Ubuntu repositories? You can search by typing

```
apt search <program name>
```

(Replace  with the actual name of the software)